# In Ada how do I initialise an array constant with a repeated number?

Tags: arrays, constants, ada

I need an array of 820 zeros for using with a mathematical function.

In C I could just write the following and the compiler would fill the array:

```
 const float EMPTY_NUMBER_A[820] = { 0.0, };
```

However in Ada that isn't possible. I really don't want to hard code the 820 elements as 0.0. Is there a way to get the compiler to do it?

```
 type Number_A is array (1 .. 820) of Float;
 EMPTY_NUMBER_A : constant Number_A := ???;
```

Using Ada 95 and GNAT.

Comment: Are you sure that C really has a feature like that? If you want that array initialized with 0.0 double values, the system initializing the complete memory area to all zero bytes will look like an array of 0.0 doubles. Does that feature really work if the array is initialized with `{ 3.0, }`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use an [aggregate](http://www.adaic.com/standards/05rm/html/RM-4-3.html):

```
Empty_Number_A : constant Number_A := (others => 0.0);
```

Comment: Much more concise then my 41 lines each of 20 zeros.

Comment: This is very powerful btw. If you want to set everything but element 20 to 0, you can do `(20 => 17.5, others => 0.0)`

Comment: Also, you could say `(others => Ada.Numerics.Float_Random.Random (Gen))` to fill with random Floats. You have to have set up the generator `Gen` first, of course.

Comment: 1 vote up. This is of the facilities of the Ada language that's motivating me to switch from C to Ada.